# Right Click on media library folder does not offer Upload File option

Tags: media-library, templates

I have a user that has create permissions for certain folders in the media library, but when I log in as that user and right-click on the folder, all I see is the create folder option.  If I click on the folder, I see the option to upload files and I can do so from that button in the right column.  Why can't I see this as an option when I right-click and how would I go about getting that option available to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload options are there only for the template:

> /sitecore/templates/System/Media/Media folder

The options can be found under `/sitecore/templates/Branches/System/Media` node:

[image]

If you can see upload option as administrator and another user cannot see those options, there must be something with the access rights which does not allow that user to upload files.

Check `Read` access to `/sitecore/templates/Branches/System/Media/Upload File` and `/sitecore/templates/Branches/System/Media/Upload File - Advanced` items.

Comment: No, these folders all use the media library template, not the general template.  What's more, when I go into the standard values for the media library folder, it includes the Upload File item as one of the Insert options, and I can see them listed when going to the insert options for the folders themselves.  Something is preventing them from coming up when right-clicking on the item though.

Comment: They do come up when I'm logged in as administrator, just not as this other user.  This user has create and read access for the folder in question and read, write, rename, and delete access to all direct children of the folder.

Comment: When you login as that user, can they read `/sitecore/templates/Branches/System/Media/Upload File` item?

Comment: Ah!  That was it!  I had inadvertantly denied access to the branch template node for a role that that user belonged to!  Good to know where that particular item resides so if this happens again I'll know where to look, thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer.